Differences between Superscalar Processors and Very Long Instruction Word Design?
Disclaimer: Somewhat new to deep diving into how the hardware actually executes instructions.
Reading "Game Engine Architecture" by Jason Gregory, and I'm on the Implicit & Explicit Parallelism Section.
So from what I'm reading from the book (and a bit from Wikipedia), I would define:

Super Scalar Processors as having multiple execution units (ALU/FPUs), and the processor is in charge of the logic that does the Out of Order Execution (taking in account data dependencies), branch prediction, and dispatches multiple instructions during a single clock-cycle
Very Long Instruction Word Architecture as, also having multiple execution units, but in this case the programmers and compilers are in charge of writing programs that take advantage of the said multiple execution units.

Are my descriptions (somewhat) correct? Is there something that I'm missing that I should be aware of?

Yeah, mostly correct.  VLIW machines do still need correct branch prediction to keep the pipeline fed, though.  And since superscalar machines actually fetch chunks of machine code (to be decoded in parallel), the branch prediction problem is fairly similar between them.  A non-VLIW needs to predict which instruction in a fetch-block is the taken branch, and discard the rest, but that prediction isn't needed until after decode.
The prediction of which (aligned 16-byte) block to fetch next is needed just as early as when a VLIW would, to have the same number of "bubble" cycles in the pipeline for a taken branch.  (Some CPUs achieve no-bubble prediction of taken branches by starting to generate a predictions before fetch has even got there, so it can be ready in time.)  Queues between stages like fetch / decode / exec can hide bubbles, especially when the earlier stages are wider than the average throughput of later stages.  At the cost of having more instructions in flight so correct branch prediction is even more important.
You can build a VLIW that looks for parallelism between multiple instruction words.  e.g. later generations of IA-64 (e.g. McKinley) would fetch/decode 2 bundles per clock, containing IIRC 3 instructions each.  An in-order superscalar that wide would have to check for hazards between every pair of those 6 instructions.  But McKinley only had to 3 simpler check in parallel, of each instruction in one bundle against every instruction in the other.
(In practice, non-VLIW machines that wide do out-of-order exec with register-renaming so hazards disappear, only true dependencies remain. And it's the hardware scheduler's job to avoid resource conflicts on each execution port.)
None of the current most-common ISAs are VLIW (x86, AArch64 / ARM, RISC-V).  They're superscalar in-order or out-of-order.  The VLIW bundle size and instruction-mix restrictions appropriate for one microarchitecture won't be for another, but they're baked into the ISA.  Letting hardware handle it all gives more flexibility in how wide to make the hardware.  Plus, it's not always easy to expose much ILP statically, especially if you don't want to unroll every loop with large machine-code size.
SIMD with short vector registers is better for data-parallel problems, and was really coming to the forefront around the early 2000s when MMX had been around for a while and SSE/SSE2 were a thing, and x86-64 made SSE2 baseline so 64-bit code could just assume support without runtime detection.  Having wider execution units instead of sending more scalar instructions through the whole pipeline is a big win.
See also

Modern Microprocessors
A 90-Minute Guide! - excellent intro to pipelining / superscalar and real-world tradeoffs like power and frequency.  It also has a section about VLIW vs. traditional superscalar.  Absolutely worth reading, I recommend this to everyone interested in CPU architecture.

The Spider and the Mountain (from 2002) - analysis of the microarchitecture of McKinley, Intel's second IA-64 design: a dual-bundle in-order VLIW, but allowing out-of-order completion.

https://www.realworldtech.com/sandy-bridge/ - a deep dive on Intel Sandybridge, the first of Intel's current family of microarchitectures.  An out-of-order exec superscalar with 4-wide issue/rename (Intel terminology: "issue" is when the front-end sends instructions to the back-end.  Most others call that "dispatch").

https://chipsandcheese.com/p/arms-cortex-a53-tiny-but-important - A deep dive of ARM Cortex-A53, an in-order 2-wide superscalar designed for low power, used as the "efficiency" cores in some big.LITTLE ARM designs, and as the only cores in some others.
That article focuses a lot on how it performs, e.g. with microbenchmarks to test how effective its branch predictor is in various situations, not so much talking about how the pieces fit together to make a working CPU.



Ty for answering, will definitely check out those resources :)

A processor that issues one instruction per clock never gets an IPC more than one. To improve performance, we must issue more than one instruction per clock. There are two main ways to achieve this: 1) VLIWs, and 2) superscalars. So, till here, we know that both are multiple-issue processors. But what are the differences? The below came to my mind.

In VLIWs, the compiler identifies and bundles independent instructions that can be issued and executed in the same cycle. In superscalars, the hardware does the task. Apparently, the compiler can help superscalars by gathering potential candidates close together.
In VLIWs, bundles include a fixed number of instructions. Thus, a fixed number of instructions are issued every cycle. In superscalar, the number of issued instructions can vary.
In VLIWs, if compiler cannot find sufficient independent instructions to fill the bundle, it must fill it with no-ops. It bloats the code and increases the code size. In superscalars, this is not the case.
In VLIWs, the compiler performs loop unrolling. This increases code size, too. In superscalars, the hardware unrolls the loops and thus, code size does not change.
In VLIWs, it is hard to maintain binary compatibility at least because most VLIWs do not incorporate hazard detection hardware. So, if the microarchitecture is changed, the machine code may no longer execute correctly, or at least will not make the most of the modified microarchitecture from a performance point of view. Thus, recompilation is necessary with a microarchitectural change in VLIWs. However, this is not the case for superscalars.
In VLIWs, instructions inside a bundle must be executed in lockstep with each other. For instance, if one gets stalled due to a cache miss, other instructions must also be stalled. This is not the case in supercalars.


In superscalars, the hardware unrolls the loops and thus, code size does not change. - What do you mean?  To reduce loop overhead and get well-pipelined execution without stall on an in-order superscalar RISC, it was necessary for compilers to unroll there, too.   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_pipelining is a technique to hide latencies of loads and ALU instructions.  Out-of-order exec can hide latencies even without software-pipelining, but it can't reduce loop overhead, you do still need to unroll for that.
